# Can't git checkout after moving a folder

Tags: git

I have created a git repo in a folder that had spaces and some non-ascii symbols in its name. Bad idea, I know, but I thought it's 2011 and mature programs can tolerate such things. Never had any problems with it btw. However, I decided to move it to a more proper folder. I also created a new branch, and started working on it. And, it's got a submodule.

Now, when I try switching back to master (git checkout master), it says,

`fatal: Not a git repository: F:/������ �����/Visual Studio 2008/Projects/OpenSource/Fubu/fubumvc/.git/modules/buildsupport`

How do I fix it?

Comment: What is the name for the repo in git?

Comment: Did you have submodules specified with a relative path / moved your submodules to a new folder too?

Comment: The name of the repo is fubumvc. I've added the submodule using the "git submodule update --init" command. And yes, I've copied the whole folder including the submodule. The problem (as I write in my own answer below) is that git keeps the absolute path (and might have a good reason for it), but perhaps it also has a command for moving a submodule?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two text files per submodule that need to be edited:

```
.git\modules\<module>\config
<module>\.git
```

Where `<module>` is the name of a submodule.